# Problemas al seleccionar una opcion en un conjunto de radio buttons - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario de preguntas con opciones, sin embargo no logro entender el porque me permite seleccionar varias opciones de radio_button en una misma pregunta, cuando deberia permitir seleccionar unicamente una opción, agradezco puedan ayudarme a solucionar este atolladero:

```
  <!-- Question -->
    <ol>
      <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
        <li><%= question.title %>

          <!-- Answer -->
            <ol type="a">
              <%= form.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
                <%= answer.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>

                <!-- Question Option -->
                  <li>
                    <% question.question_options.each do |question_option| %>
                      <!-- Answer Option -->
                        <%= answer.fields_for :answer_options do |answer_option| %>
                            <%= answer_option.radio_button :question_option_id, question_option.id %>
                            <%= answer_option.label :question_option_id, question_option.title %>
                            <%# answer_option.hidden_field :answer_id %>                      

                            <!-- Sub Question Option -->
                              <ol type="a">
                              <% question_option.sub_question_options.each do |sub_question_option| %>

                                  <!-- Sub Question Option -->
                                    <%= answer_option.fields_for :sub_answer_options do |sub_answer_option| %>
                                      <li>
                                        <%= sub_answer_option.check_box :sub_question_option_id, { }, sub_question_option.id, nil %>
                                        <%= sub_answer_option.label :sub_question_option_id, sub_question_option.title %>
                                      </li>
                                    <% end %>
                                  <!-- End Sub Question Option -->

                              <% end %>
                              </ol>
                            <!-- End Sub Question Option -->

                        <% end %>                            
                      <!-- End Answer Option -->

                    <% end %>                
                  </li>
                <!-- End Question Option -->

              <% end %>
            </ol>
          <!-- End Answer -->

        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  <!-- End Question -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso en general sucede cuando tienes dos radio buttons con distinto name:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="nombre1" value="uno"> tengo nombre1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="nombre2" value="dos"> tengo nombre2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="nombre2" value="tres"> tengo nombre2
</form>
```

Podrías revisar en el html generado cuáles son los name que rails les está asignando y hacer los cambios en tu radio button para que funcione correctamente (así a primeras, no veo cuál pueda ser el problema). En el peor de los casos, podrías considerar el crear manualmente tus radio buttons con [`radio_button_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag).

Comment: Saludos Alter, efectivamente funciono, me permite seleccionar uno sola de las opciones, sin embargo al cambiar el Name, no almacena la opcion en cuestion, aparentemente Rails almacena la opcion en base a la posicion de un Array que este mismo crea, es decir: `name="respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][1][question_option_id]"`, de que forma podria cambiar el name, y permitirme almacenar siempre la opcion Alter